# How can I get the name of a language in any other language, based on IETF language tag

Tags: json, ietf-bcp-47

I'm looking for a way to get the name of a language in any other language, based on a IETF language tag. For example: I have a list of IETF language tags ('en', 'fr', 'nl', 'de' , ...) and I want them mapped to the language display name of my current locale (e.g. Dutch):

- 'en' => 'Engels'
- 'fr' => 'Frans'
- 'nl' => 'Nederlands'
- 'de' => 'Duits'

I've searched NPM but found nothing. I would prefer a list in JSON, but I will settle for any language/format.

**EDIT: Solution**

This is how you can implement this using `cldr-localenames-modern` (see @korpiq's answer below):

```js
import en from 'cldr-localenames-modern/main/en/languages.json';
import nl from 'cldr-localenames-modern/main/nl/languages.json';

const localeDisplayNames = {
    en: en.main.en.localeDisplayNames.languages,
    nl: nl.main.nl.localeDisplayNames.languages
};

export function getLanguageDisplayName(language, locale) {
    const languages = localeDisplayNames[locale] ?? localeDisplayNames['en'];

    return languages[language];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I have found so far: https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr-json/tree/main/cldr-json/cldr-localenames-modern

However, there the `displayNames` in each locale's `languages.json` are tagged by 2-3 letter codes, instead of the `<language>-<country>` naming used for the locales themselves. For two-letter names, I guess it's sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly how I ended up implementing this...